# How do I turn on focus follows mouse?

Tags: mouse

I just installed ubuntu 11.10 on a laptop of mine. Where do you turn on window autofocus on mouse hovering in this new version?

I used to be able to do it very easily in 11.04.

UPDATE: I'm looking for "Select windows when the mouse moves over them"